# ArcGIS Python API append new record

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to insert a python dict record to the hosted online service.
I am getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\layer.py", line 2824, in edit_features
if isinstance(adds[0], dict):
KeyError: 0

My dict is:

```json
{
    'OBJECTID': 21641,
    'Shape': (689718.442176355, 15309636.152327772),
    'ANCILLARYROLE': 0,
    'ENABLED': 1,
    'CREATIONUSER': 'U437198',
    'DATECREATED': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 11, 0, 0),
    'DATEMODIFIED': None,
    'LASTUSER': None,
    'SUBTYPECD': 1,
    'OWNER': 'NYSEG',
    'WORKORDERID': '801000483026',
    'PROJECTNUMBER': None,
    'PROPERTYUNITCODE': None,
    'WORKMANAGEMENTSYSTEMCODE': None,
    'GASTRACEWEIGHT': 541589504,
    'SYMBOLROTATION': 88.94467079,
    'DIVISION': 'DANS',
    'FACILITYID': '61020001',
    'EQUIPMENTID': None,
    'COMMENTS': None,
    'INSERVICEDATE': None,
    'MATERIAL': 'PL',
    'VALVEDIAMETER': '4',
    'VALVETYPE': 'BAL',
    'VALVEUSE': 'ISO',
    'ANSIPRESSURERATING': None,
    'BONDEDINDICATOR': 'N',
    'CLOCKWISETOCLOSE': 'C',
    'DEPTH': None,
    'DEPTHTONUT': None,
    'EMERISOLATIONSYSSTATUS': None,
    'GASPRESSURESYSTEMSTATUS': None,
    'GASSYSTEMSTATUS': None,
    'GROUNDLEVELINDICATOR': None,
    'INSULATEDINDICATOR': None,
    'NORMALPOSITION': 1,
    'PRESENTPOSITION': 1,
    'OPERATINGCLASSIFICATION': 'NC',
    'LOCATIONDESCRIPTION': None,
    'DIMENSIONTIE1': None,
    'DIMENSIONTIE2': None,
    'MANUFACTURER': None,
    'MODEL': None,
    'EMERISOLATIONSYSOBJECTID': None,
    'GASPRESSURESYSTEMOBJECTID': 830,
    'GASSYSTEMOBJECTID': 34,
    'SAP_FUNCTIONALLOCATION': None,
    'SAP_EQUIPMENTNUMBER': None,
    'CIVILDIVISION': None,
    'LEGACYID': None,
    'INSTALLATIONDATE': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 6, 0, 0),
    'TURNSTOCLOSE': 0.25,
    'GLOBALID': '{B10CFD9F-2DB7-40C2-B708-E222222A0AED}',
    'OPERATINGSTATE': 'ACTIVE',
    'CUSTOMERCOUNT': None,
    'CUSTOMERCOUNTDATE': None,
    'MAINTENANCE_JOB': 'N',
    'CPSYSTEMSTATUS': None,
    'DIMENSIONTIE3': None,
    'ELEVATION': None,
    'ELECTRONICMARKERS': None,
    'FLOC_ID': None
}
```

MY code is :

```
import arcpy
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
lyr_url = 'https://services6.arcgis.com/A1NU60yx0I8XSDFS/arcgis/rest/services/ValvesTest/FeatureServer/0'

layer = FeatureLayer(lyr_url)
feature_count = layer.query(return_count_only=True)
print("Feature Count: ", feature_count)
layer.manager.truncate()
feature_count = layer.query(return_count_only=True)
print("Now Feature Count: ", feature_count)

fc = "E:\\ABC\\gaspopups.gdb\\DistributionGasValve"

feature = None
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["*"])
row = next(cursor)
feature = {field: value for field, value in zip(cursor.fields, row)}
layer.edit_features(adds=feature )
```

How to go about it?

Comment: At least the shape value in your dict doesn't look right, it needs to be a dict, too, e.g. `{"x": 123, "y": 456 }`. See the documentation [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/editing-features)

Comment: Also, adds expects an array, so that would be `adds=[feature]`.